# How to set up Angular2 CLI Project and Node.js app from the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I created a project using the angular2 cli. I also created a separate node js application that acts as the backend. I would like to move my front-end application into the node app, so that I can run both apps using node server.js. My server.js looks like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
...
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/src/index.html');
});
app.listen(8000);
```

My index.html from the angular2 cli looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

When I now run node server.js and browse to http://localhost:8000/ then I can see the "Loading..." message, but nothing appears after and there are no errors in the console either.

Comment: You are referencing the wrong location`./app/src/index.html`. It should be `/src/index.html` because your node application serving the files from `app` directory. `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'))` . So you should directly refer the location considering `/app` as a root.

Comment: @KunalSharma I can see the "Loading..." label in the browser, which indicates that the location is correct. I tried to change it anyways, and received a "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" error.

Comment: You should upload a plnkr, that will probably help better. Maybe some kind of path referencing issue. Check your console's network tab.

Comment: @KunalSharma I will try to upload a plnkr, though I am not sure if that will work there, because the CLI generates a ton of files. There are no errors in the network tab either.

Comment: update the question with the relevant code, that can also serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What you should really do is create a prod build with the angular cli in some folder (`ng build --prod -o /somefolder`) (o is for output), and than have node statically server that folder with `app.use(express.static...)`. Than you can add one route to just return the index.html page so your url will not contain the whole folder path (ex: localhost/somefolder/index.html) (this path is ugly).

This is the best way because the angular app is still separate and not mixed anywhere with the nodejs logic.

Comment: This will require that I build my version anytime I change anything in angular right? While this works for production it will be somewhat useless in development right?

Comment: Well in development you can use ng build --watch -o /somefolder and it will watch the files and recompile on its own (its a bit slower because ng serve has the files in-memory). Also having the files physically on a disk can help you debug in webstorm if you need it ever